# not receiving pushNotification in android

Tags: push-notification, push, google-cloud-messaging

I had configured gcm pushnotification client receiver for android. The server is receiving send success response from google but the message is not receiving at the client side device. The app server uses gcm_on_rails gem for sending push notification (gcm_on_rails link: https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails implemenntation). I am stuck at this point for several days, any helps will be appreciate.

This is my Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.glympse.android.sendlite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- GLYMPSE API - Needed to send Glympses via SMS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <!-- GLYMPSE API - Needed to read contacts if using the Recipients editor from the Send Wizard -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <!-- GLYMPSE API - Used to query network connection status before attempting network activity -->
    <!-- Docs:   Allows applications to access information about networks -->
    <!-- Install: View network connections -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- GLYMPSE API - Used to create a default user profile (nickname/avatar) -->
    <!-- Optional but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Docs:    Allows an application to read the user's contacts data. -->
    <!-- Install: Read your contacts -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <!-- GLYMPSE API - Used to create a default user profile (nickname/avatar) -->
    <!-- Optional but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Docs:    Allows an application to read the user's personal profile data. -->
    <!-- Install: Read your own contact card -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <permission
        android:name="com.glympse.android.sendlite.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.glympse.android.sendlite.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ChaffeoSplash"            
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.glympse.android.login.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.glympse.android.home.Home"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.glympse.android.acceptrejectrides.ShowMyList"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".IndividualBookings"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NoRidesAccRej"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.glympse.android.yourrides.YourRides"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StartRide"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NoRidesYourRides"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabGroupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabGroup1Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TabsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabsActivity2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabsActivity1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GlympseSendLiteDemoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <!-- GLYMPSE API - This is required to make the GlympseSendWizard configurator work. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.glympse.android.kit.send.GlympseSendWizard"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize" >
        </activity>

        <!-- GLYMPSE API - This is required to be notified, when Glympse service is restarted. -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".GlympseLiteWrapper$ServiceReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.glympse.android.hal.service.STARTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".EndRide" >
        </activity>

         <receiver
            android:name="com.glympse.android.notifications.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.glympse.android.sendlite" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.glympse.android.notifications.GCMNotificationIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Broadcast receiver :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


         // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());

         // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);


    }
}
```

This is my GCM service class :

```
    public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        System.out.println("###############GCM Message type---> " + messageType);
        System.out.println("GCM intent.getStringExtra()---> " + msg);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } 
            else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } 
            else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                    + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

//              sendNotification(""+extras.get(DriverUtils.MESSAGE_KEY));


                sendNotification(""+extras.get("message"));

                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                System.out.println("GCM GCM GCM" + extras.toString());

            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        System.out.println("MESSAGE : " + msg);             

        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChaffeoSplash.class);
       PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Build notification
        // Actions are just fake
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Chaffeo")
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;// hide the notification after its selected
        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // hide the notification after its selected  
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
}
```

Could any one help me solving this problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the following code :

```
     // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
```

you are saying that the `GCMNotificationIntentService` is located in the main package of the application. However, your `GCMNotificationIntentService` is located in `com.glympse.android.notifications`, while the main package of your app is `com.glympse.android.sendlite`.

You can fix it this way :

```
     // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getPackage().getName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
```